# How to use product entity if child view exists

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, npgsql

ASP.NET 5 MVC Shopping cart application uses EF Core with Npgsql data provider.
Database contains products table

```
create table Product (
  Product char(20) primary key;
  Description char(50);
  )
```

It is mapped to Product entity by EF Core Scaffold

```
public class Product {
  public string Product1 { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  }
```

Read-only product view entity has special shadow properties which do not exist in database and in Product class:

```
public class ShopToode: Product {
  public decimal CartPrice { get; set; }
  }

public DbSet<ShopToode> ShopToodes { get; set; }
public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

ShopToode is used only to view data using FromSqlRaw:

```
var tooteinfo = await ctx.ShopToodes.FromSqlRaw(@"select *, 
  1.2 as CartPrice 
  from Product").AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

Trying to get product like

```
 var t = ctx.Products.First();
```

throws error

> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42703: column t.Discriminator
> does not exist

How to use Product entity if view also exists ?

Comment: looks like you create the table `Product` using a manual script? That's the issue here. If auto-generated by EFCore, it should include a `Discriminator` column for the TPH mapping. The `Product` table contains both data for `Product` and `ShopToode` so it requires a `Discriminator` column to help identity each type.

Comment: PRoduct and ShopToode contain same product rows. No discriminator is needed

Comment: not sure what you mean but if `Product` & `ShopToode` are in the ***same*** table, then a discriminator is required here. In fact for such kind of inheritance without any configuration to specify ***separate tables*** mapped to each entity type, the `Table-Per-Hierarchy` scheme will be used by default. That scheme always need a discriminator column and in fact that should be generated by EFCore (and can be configured to have a different name and types), unless you create your table using manual script. Finally, the error says everything, it complains about the missing *Discriminator* column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what a ShopToode is, but it sounds like a Shop Cart Item. Unless a ShopToode needs to be actually saved to the database, I wouldn't have it declared like an entity, and definitely would *not* inherit from Product. You can declare a view model or DTO that you intend to serialize or chuck in a session variable and project details from a product to it:

```
var tooteinfo = await ctx.Products
    .Select(x => new TooteInfo
    {
       ProductId = x.ProductId,
       // ...
       CartPrice = 1.2
    }).ToListAsync();
```

For a structure that is persisted to data where I had a Cart (for a User), with CartProduct linking a product to a cart, and a Product, this is more a case for a many-to-many relationship:

```
public class Cart
{
    [Key]
    public int CartId { get; set; } 
    public int UserId {get; set; }
    // ...

    public virtual ICollection<CartProduct> CartProducts { get; set; } = new List<CartProduct>();
}

public class CartProduct
{
    [Key, Column(Order=0), ForeignKey("Cart")]
    public int CartId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order=1), ForeignKey("Product")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    
    [NotMapped]
    public decimal CartPrice
    {
        get { return UnitPrice * Quantity; }
    }

    public virtual Cart Cart { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

From there you can query a Cart and select details from CartProducts and through that to Product to build a view model.

Comment: In shopping cart Product has about 200 properties and properties are different in different shops. Every shop has different Product table and class scaffolded at installation. Datacontext is in separarate assembly different in different shops. Your code requires manually hard-coding Product properties when ShopToode DTO is used. This is not possible. How to create code which does not require hard -coded properties like `SELECT *, 1.2 AS CartPrice FROM Product` in question.

Comment: It looks like ShopToode should created as separate DTO entity and should contain only reference (product id) to product entity, removing inheritance?